# Is it possible to get a TextClock's value to string?

Tags: java, android, string

I have an android TextClock in my main activity. Is there any way I can get the value of that TextClock to a string? I have tried:

```
public TextClock clock;
public String clockValue;


clock = (TextClock) findViewById(R.id.TextClock1);
clockValue = clock.getText.toString;

if(clockValue.equals("09:30")) {
Log.e ("Works")
}
```

That did not work

Comment: The `TextClock#getText()` method will work, but only after the `TextClock` has been laid out; i.e., after it is visible on-screen. Also, it's default formatting will not have any leading zeroes, and will include AM/PM.

Comment: Thanks, I have been trying for hours to make this work! :D

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get TextClock's value immediately.You can use the **handler.postDelayed** to get it per second.